# Exporting bindings in Orchard 1.6

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm having problems exporting (via the Export module) a binding I've created through the Bindings tab on the Query page, has anyone come across this before?

I tried first on my project I'm working on, when that didn't work, I set up a clean install of Orchard and tried there. However the binding still does not appear in the exported xml, the query I created pointing to the binding comes out ok and is still pointing to the type.

I checked in the error log but there's nothing in there...

Any thoughts or advice are welcome.

Comment: That may be a bug. Please file it in the issue tracker on CodePlex.

Comment: On the advice of @Bertrand Le Roy, I've filed a bug on this http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hitting this bug myself, I decided to write the export/import functionality for member bindings.
I added it as a module to the gallery..

[Orchard Gallery: Contrib.ImportExportBindings](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.ImportExportBindings/1.0)

[Github: Orchard-ImportExportBindings](https://github.com/StanleyGoldman/Orchard-ImportExportBindings)

It will do the trick.
I'm not sure it should be in the source of orchard though.

Answer (score 1):

On the advice of @Bertrand Le Roy, I've filed a bug on this http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19447